# Rename Uploaded File in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

What I want to do is add a number to the beginning of the file name so I don't have a duplicate file name in the folder.

So I choose my file "example.pdf" and upload, I got the the part of the code that looks like this:

```
move_uploaded_file($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][0], $path1);
```

In this line of code above can I add a variable to change the file name to "1-example.pdf"?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the new name as part of the second parameter of `move_uploaded_file`:

```
move_uploaded_file($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][0], "$path1/example.pdf");
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The `move_uploaded_file` method's second parameter is not only the path, but the filename to place the file. Try something like this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][0], $path1.'/[PUT NUMBER HERE]-'.$_FILES['ufile']['name'][0]);
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I actual figured it out right after I posted this. Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

What I did is that I created a random number which goes until to a million so the program will generate a number to rename a picture  like this .though I did not use exactly your codes in your question .

```
#Rename images 
  $rand = rand(0,1000000);
  $rename = $rand.$name;
  $move = move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$target.$rename);
```